# How can I adjust the bounds of the x tick values that are automatically chosen by matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, yfinance

I have a graph that shows the closing price of a stock throughout a day at each five minute interval. The x axis shows the time and the range of x values is from 9:30 to 4:00 (16:00).
The problem is that the automatic bounds for the x axis go from 9:37 to 16:07 and I really just want it from 9:30 to 16:00.

The code I am currently running is this:

```
    stk = yf.Ticker(ticker)
    his = stk.history(interval="5m", start=start, end=end).values.tolist() #open - high - low - close - volume
    x = []
    y = []
    count = 0
    five_minutes = datetime.timedelta(minutes = 5)
    for bar in his:
        x.append((start + five_minutes * count))#.strftime("%H:%M"))
        count = count + 1
        y.append(bar[3])
    plt.clf()
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M"))
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(interval=30))
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
    plt.show()
```

And it produces this plot (currently a link because I am on a new user account):

[image]

I thought I was supposed to use the axis.set_data_interval function providing, so I did so by providing datetime objects representing 9:30 and 16:00 as the min and the max. This gave me the error:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'datetime.datetime'

Is there another a way for me to be able to adjust the first xtick and still have it automatically fill in the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be fixed by adjusting the way you use the `mdates` tick locator. Here is an example based on the one shared by r-beginners to make it comparable. Note that I use the [pandas plotting function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) for convenience. The `x_compat=True` argument is needed for it to work with `mdates`:

```
import pandas as pd                # 1.1.3
import yfinance as yf              # 0.1.54
import matplotlib.dates as mdates  # 3.3.2

# Import data
ticker = 'AAPL'
stk = yf.Ticker(ticker)
his = stk.history(period='1D', interval='5m')

# Create pandas plot with appropriately formatted x-axis ticks
ax = his.plot(y='Close', x_compat=True, figsize=(10,5))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(byminute=[0, 30]))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M', tz=his.index.tz))
ax.legend(frameon=False)
ax.figure.autofmt_xdate(rotation=0, ha='center')
```

[image: plot_xticks]

Comment: Thank you! This worked exactly as I intended after I changed my MinuteLocator to your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The sample data was created by obtaining Apple's stock price from Yahoo Finance. The desired five-minute interval labels are a list of strings obtained by using the date function to get the start and end times at five-minute intervals.
Based on this, the x-axis is drawn as a graph of the number of five-minute intervals and the closing price, and the x-axis is set to any interval by slicing.

```
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ticker = 'AAPL'

stk = yf.Ticker(ticker)
his = stk.history(period='1D',interval="5m")
his.reset_index(inplace=True)

time_rng = pd.date_range('09:30','15:55', freq='5min')
labels = ['{:02}:{:02}'.format(t.hour,t.minute) for t in time_rng]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.arange(len(his))
y = his.Close

ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_xticks(x[::3])
ax.set_xticklabels(labels[::3], rotation=45)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Terrific! I was looking to avoid having to set the ticks on my own but this is a concise and simple way to do that and it works exactly as I would need it to.

Comment: My answer creates a different scale than the real time. The other answer controls the display of the real time at 30-minute intervals. Since the real data happens to be at 5 minute intervals, the value and the scale are correct, but if it is 37 minutes like your data, it will be off the scale. You can see this by drawing a grid line.